# Handshake problems

Tags: autobahn, crossbar, autobahnws, autobahnjs

I am having a bit of a problem when using crossbar.
I start running autobahn python backend and autobahn js frontend and everything seems normal until I get this error:

```
2016-08-01T14:12:40+0000 [Router       9051] failing WebSocket opening handshake ('WebSocket connection denied: origin 'null' not allowed')
```

Any idea why? and how to solve it?

EDIT:

Here is some code (I'm using WAMP) but i believe the problem isn't code related because it has worked in other networks, just not in the one im in right now. Anyways:

**Frontend:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello WAMP/Browser - Frontend</h1>
      <p>Open JavaScript console to watch output.</p>
      <script>AUTOBAHN_DEBUG = true;</script>
      <script src="http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.min.jgz"></script>

      <script>
         // the URL of the WAMP Router (Crossbar.io)
         //
         var wsuri = "ws://192.168.4.24:8080/";


         // the WAMP connection to the Router
         //
         var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
            url: wsuri,
            realm: "joyPadRealm"
         });


         // timers
         //
         var t1, t2;


         // fired when connection is established and session attached
         //
         connection.onopen = function (session, details) {

            console.log("Connected");

            // SUBSCRIBE to a topic and receive events
            //
            function on_counter (args) {
               var counter = args[0];
               console.log("on_counter() event received with counter " + counter);
            }
            session.subscribe('com.example.oncounter', on_counter).then(
               function (sub) {
                  console.log('subscribed to topic');
               },
               function (err) {
                  console.log('failed to subscribe to topic', err);
               }
            );


            // PUBLISH an event every second
            //
            t1 = setInterval(function () {

               session.publish('com.example.onhello', ['Hello from JavaScript (browser)']);
               console.log("published to topic 'com.example.onhello'");
            }, 1000);


            // REGISTER a procedure for remote calling
            //
            function mul2 (args) {
               var x = args[0];
               var y = args[1];
               console.log("mul2() called with " + x + " and " + y);
               return x * y;
            }
            session.register('com.example.mul2', mul2).then(
               function (reg) {
                  console.log('procedure registered');
               },
               function (err) {
                  console.log('failed to register procedure', err);
               }
            );


            // CALL a remote procedure every second
            //
            var x = 0;

            t2 = setInterval(function () {

               session.call('com.example.add2', [x, 18]).then(
                  function (res) {
                     console.log("add2() result:", res);
                  },
                  function (err) {
                     console.log("add2() error:", err);
                  }
               );

               x += 3;
            }, 1000);
         };


         // fired when connection was lost (or could not be established)
         //
         connection.onclose = function (reason, details) {
            console.log("Connection lost: " + reason);
            if (t1) {
               clearInterval(t1);
               t1 = null;
            }
            if (t2) {
               clearInterval(t2);
               t2 = null;
            }
         }


         // now actually open the connection
         //
         connection.open();

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Backend:**

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.logger import Logger
from os import environ
from autobahn.twisted.util import sleep
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner
from autobahn.wamp.exception import ApplicationError



class AppSession(ApplicationSession):

    log = Logger()

    @inlineCallbacks
    def onJoin(self, details):

        ## SUBSCRIBE to a topic and receive events
        ##
        def onhello(msg):
            self.log.info("event for 'onhello' received: {msg}", msg=msg)

        sub = yield self.subscribe(onhello, 'com.example.onhello')
        self.log.info("subscribed to topic 'onhello'")


        ## REGISTER a procedure for remote calling
        ##
        def add2(x, y):
            self.log.info("add2() called with {x} and {y}", x=x, y=y)
            return x + y

        reg = yield self.register(add2, 'com.example.add2')
        self.log.info("procedure add2() registered")


        ## PUBLISH and CALL every second .. forever
        ##
        counter = 0
        while True:

            ## PUBLISH an event
            ##
            yield self.publish('com.example.oncounter', counter)
            self.log.info("published to 'oncounter' with counter {counter}",
                          counter=counter)
            counter += 1


            ## CALL a remote procedure
            ##
            try:
                res = yield self.call('com.example.mul2', counter, 3)
                self.log.info("mul2() called with result: {result}",
                              result=res)
            except ApplicationError as e:
                ## ignore errors due to the frontend not yet having
                ## registered the procedure we would like to call
                if e.error != 'wamp.error.no_such_procedure':
                    raise e


            yield sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = ApplicationRunner(
        environ.get("AUTOBAHN_DEMO_ROUTER", u"ws://192.168.4.24:8080/"),
        u"joyPadRealm",
    )
    runner.run(AppSession)
```

**config.json**

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "controller": {},
    "workers": [
        {
            "type": "router",
            "realms": [
                {
                    "name": "joyPadRealm",
                    "roles": [
                        {
                            "name": "anonymous",
                            "permissions": [
                                {
                                    "uri": "",
                                    "match": "prefix",
                                    "allow": {
                                        "call": true,
                                        "register": true,
                                        "publish": true,
                                        "subscribe": true
                                    },
                                    "disclose": {
                                        "caller": false,
                                        "publisher": false
                                    },
                                    "cache": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "transports": [
        {
            "type": "websocket",
            "endpoint": {
                "type": "tcp",
                "port": 8080
            },
            "url": "ws://localhost:8080/"
           }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should add some code, so it is easier to investigate your problem. Right now it just looks like your origin is null instead of the value it should be.